# Angularjs performance on LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

```
    console.log(new Date().getSeconds())
    var searchFields = localStorage.searchFields;
    if(searchFields) {
        $scope.fields = JSON.parse(searchFields);
    } else {
        // Make http call and populate $scope.fields
    }
    console.log(new Date().getSeconds())
```

If the flow gets into if condition then the DOM takes 4 seconds to render $scope.fields. But in the else condition it takes only 2 seconds.

In both the cases the response is same and the response size is of 125Kb.

Why is there so much delay when using localStorage?

I also tried to use [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) but that too takes 4 seconds.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that one could reproduce it ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably parsing JSON takes too much time. Did you tested:

console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
var searchFields = localStorage.searchFields;
console.log(new Date().getSeconds());